# DCA files cause build errors

Tags: forms, vb6

I am working on a VB6 application and I have requested to change the platinum gray style forms' to our new format.
In order to do that, I have first modified the `Backcolor`attribute as `H8000000E` (it was `H8000000F` previously) for labels, frames and forms.

Those forms were saved with `.Dsr` extension. 
Each form is having three fils with `.Dsr`, `.DCA` and `.dsx` extensions.

After I modified the `Backcolor`, I compiled the code and it ran successfully. Then I close the project, reopen it and run again. 
Then I got the `Error in Loading DLL` error.

We didn't commit the .DCA files to git. But once I committed one .DCA file and it caused a build failure. But this is occurring without even commit any changes.

I am still unable to find a reason why this occurred.

Could anybody please help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the .DCA files set and it resolve the problem.

DCA is a temporary type information cache file created by Visual Basic. It is used by VB to speed up compilation.